# multiple accumulator object in monodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am New To mongo db and i am writing a query to fetch top three customers based on their call duration from my collection below given is my query

```
db.getCollection("dailylogs20190314").aggregate([
  {
    $match: { company_name: { $in: ["TCS PVT LTD - FIXED LINE", "TCS -SON"] } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$customer_msisdn",
      max_duration: { $sum: { $toInt: "$duration" } }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { max_duration: -1 } },
  { $limit: 3 }
]);
```

this query gives me result as following

```
_id            max_duration
-------------- ------------
924230000000  | 11988005
922136172600  | 1185000
922136182353  | 3381
```

But i want company_name against each row too how would i achieve that what i want is

```
_id            max_duration   company_name
-------------- ----------------------------
924230000000  | 11988005  |   TCS -SON
922136172600  | 1185000   |   TCS -Fixed Line
922136182353  | 3381      |   TCS -Fixed Line
```

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator to return the first document after applying the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

```
db.getCollection("dailylogs20190314").aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "company_name": { "$in": ["TCS PVT LTD - FIXED LINE", "TCS -SON"] }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$customer_msisdn",
    "max_duration": { "$sum": { "$toInt": "$duration" } },
    "company_name": { "$first": "$company_name" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "max_duration": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 3 }
])
```